# Apache: force HTTPS on when behind SSL-terminating reverse proxy

Tags: apache, apache-config

I am using apache 2.4.57 behind an SSL-terminating reverse-proxy (Traefik in my case). Traefik takes https requests and proxies them to apache port 80 with the following HTTP headers set: `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For`.

My problem is that I cannot get apache to recognize that requests are actually using the https scheme. This is problematic because I have a ton of `RewriteRule` configurations that result in 302 responses which contain an http scheme like this: `location: http://myhostname.org/mypath`. This sometimes results in MixedContent errors with my application.

Ideally, I'd like to add this to my `VirtualHost` config:

`SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on`

But the `HTTPS` variable always remains `off`. In fact, even when I configure `SetEnv HTTPS on` the `HTTPS` variable still stays `off`.

Abbreviated config is something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
    RewriteEngine On

    # Debug: Show X-Forwarded-Proto header and HTTPS variable
    RewriteRule ^/debug$ /debug?xfp=%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}&https=%{HTTPS} [R,L]

    # Lots of other RewriteRules below...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try a test with curl I get:

```
curl -v https://myhostname.org/debug 2>&1 |grep location
< location: http://myhostname.org/debug?xfp=https&https=off
```

Why doesn't this work? How do I force `HTTPS` on and make all my `RewriteRules` return a location with https?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using a modified version of the answer provided by @VonC. Note that `SetEnvIf` works to set a user environment variable, it apparently just can't be used to override the built-in apache variable `HTTPS`. This solution unfortunately required me to manually change all my `RewriteRule` stanzas.

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTP_SCHEME=https
SetEnvIf HTTP_SCHEME ^$ HTTP_SCHEME=http

# prepend scheme/host to substitution portion of each RewriteRule 
RewriteRule ^/foo$ %{ENV:HTTP_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/bar [R,L]
```

In the future, I'm hoping that [apache/httpd PR 191](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/191) provides an easier way to address this issue.

Comment: I have edited the answer below to reference the patch mentioned in PR 191.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OP Noky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751020/noky) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003175/apache-force-https-on-when-behind-ssl-terminating-reverse-proxy/77035765#comment135828100_77035765) that [`SetEnvIf` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) (in `SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on`) did not set the built-in apache `HTTPS` variable described in the [`mod_ssl` docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html), it sets a user variable with the same name.

You could try [`mod_remoteip`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_remoteip.html) in Apache, but since, in your case, Traefik is already sending `X-Forwarded-Proto`, you can use instead a conditional [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to manipulate the URL schema.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Set an environment variable if X-Forwarded-Proto is https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^https$
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_SCHEME:https]
    
    # Fallback to http if the above condition did not match
    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_SCHEME} ^$
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_SCHEME:http]
    
    # Your existing RewriteRules here, but modify to use the determined scheme
    RewriteRule ^/debug$ %{ENV:HTTP_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/debug?xfp=%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}&https=%{ENV:HTTP_SCHEME} [R,L]
    
    # other RewriteRules
</VirtualHost>
```

`RewriteCond` is used to inspect `X-Forwarded-Proto`. If it is "https", we set an environment variable `HTTP_SCHEME` to "https". Then in your `RewriteRule`, we use this environment variable to construct the URLs.

That should yield URLs with the correct scheme in the `Location` header for 302 responses.

Note: Noky also points out to [apache/httpd PR 191](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/191) "mod_remoteip is extended by multiple options handy for frontend proxies moving traffic to Apache backends", which would need to be applied.

Dec. 2023: [apache/httpd PR 191](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/191#issuecomment-1850121327) proposes [`httpd-2.4-remoteip-2.4.58-20231211.patch`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/files/13636271/httpd-2.4-remoteip-2.4.58-20231211.patch), which could be applied to Apache 2.4.58.

```cpp
/**
 * This hook allows modules that virtualize SSL state (i.e. mod_remoteip)
 * based on the data from remote frontend to register their inquiry function
 * for checking if a remote frontend connection is using SSL for the request.
 * @param r The current request
 * @return OK iff the frontend connection is using SSL, DONE if not,
 *         DECLINED iff the state is undefined (let later modules decide).
 * @ingroup hooks
 */
AP_DECLARE_HOOK(int,remote_is_ssl,(request_rec *r))

/**
 * Return != 0 iff the frontend connection for the request is encrypted with SSL.
 * If there is no data from the hook (DECLINED), falls back to ap_ssl_conn_is_ssl()
 * and so corresponds to the local connection security state (we are the frontend).
 * @param r The current request
 */
AP_DECLARE(int) ap_remote_is_ssl(request_rec *r);
```

Comment: First off, I was hoping to avoid modifying scores of `RewriteRule` stanzas by prepending the scheme & host, but I might have to. The idea is sound.

As for `SetEnvIf` not working due to an ordering issue, that is not true. I found that `SetEnvIf` actually did work, but it did not set the built-in apache `HTTPS` variable described in the [mod_ssl docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html), it set a **user variable** with the same name!

Finally, `mod_remoteip` doesn't help now, but there is a [PR which might just solve the issue](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/191)!

Comment: @Noky Good catch. Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer and included your comments.